# Does Indiana Jones have a literary inspiration or equivalent?

Tags: inspiration, indiana-jones

I am aware of speculation that Indiana Jones is possibly based on one or more hybrids of historical individuals, but does the character have a literary forerunner?

Comment: Is this question specifically about the Indiana Jones films?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The origins are well documented on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones#Origins_and_inspirations).

George Lucas was very public about the character of Indy being inspired by [Scrooge McDuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Scrooge) in a treasure hunting storyline, although [Alan Quartermain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_Quatermain) and [Professor Challenger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Challenger) are taken to be more direct references.